# Instead it will show two Push notifications that will show two in one like whatsapp

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, parse-android-sdk

Now, when I send 2 push notifications ( I use parse android) I am showing on my device 2 icons in the phone bar(2 icons, 2 messages).
I want to see only 1 icon and 2 messages like Whatsapp.

How I do this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you sending it? From the device or from your backend

Comment: from the device:
 ParsePush androidPush = new ParsePush();
 androidPush.setMessage("test");

         androidPush.sendInBackground();